Unable to use the forest package to make a tree
I am a little new to the forest package. Here is how I setup my forest package -
\newenvironment{abc}
{
\forest
  for tree={
    font=\sffamily\small, % <- Adjust font size here
    grow'=0,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    align=left, base=bottom,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    inner sep=0,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom,  align=left, base=bottom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
   }
}
{
\endforest
}


Here is a minimal example of how I utilize the package -
\begin{abc}
[Parent
    [Child 1]
    [Child 2]
  ] 
\end{abc}

Unfortunately, this is the output that I get -
for tree= font=, grow’=0, child anchor=west, parent anchor=south, align=left, base=bottom,
anchor=west, calign=first, inner sep=0, edge path= [draw, edge] (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) —- node[fill,inner
sep=1.25pt] (.child anchor)edge label; , before typesetting nodes= if n=1 insert before=[,phantom, align=left,
base=bottom] , fit=band, before computing xy=l=15pt, [Parent [Child 1] [Child 2] ]

Also, Overleaf gives me the error at \begin{abc} stating - Undefined control sequence

Edit 1: Here is a minimal working example of what I am trying to do. Although this works, the above code didn't work -
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{abc}
{
\forest
  for tree={
    font=\sffamily\small, % <- Adjust font size here
    grow'=0,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    align=left, base=bottom,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    inner sep=0,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom,  align=left, base=bottom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
   }
}
{
\endforest
}


\begin{abc}
  [Parent
    [Child 1]
    [Child 2]
  ] 
\end{abc}
\end{document}


Your examples can‘t compile …

@MS-SPO I have fixed it.

If you modified this code from somewhere, please provide a link. (I say this because the code doesn't really look like somebody's first go with forest;) and the original context is often useful.)

This sort of environment definition does not work with Forest, because the forest environment internally grabs its body, i.e. everything up to \end{forest}, which it does not get with OP's definition of abc.
If one really wants to define a new "forest environment", using the LaTeX3 way and argument type b (for document body) is the way to go. (If you expect the content of the nodes to contain paragraph breaks, use argument type +b.) (In the old times, we would do this using NewEnviron of package environ.)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{abc}{b}{%
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      font=\sffamily\small, % <- Adjust font size here
      grow'=0,
      child anchor=west,
      parent anchor=south,
      align=left, base=bottom,
      anchor=west,
      calign=first,
      inner sep=0,
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      before typesetting nodes={
        if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom,  align=left, base=bottom]}}
        {}
      },
      fit=band,
      before computing xy={l=15pt},
    }
    #1
  \end{forest}%
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{abc}
  [Parent
    [Child 1]
    [Child 2]
  ] 
\end{abc}
\end{document}

However, I suggest defining a forest-internal style, like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  abc/.style={
    for tree={
      font=\sffamily\small, % <- Adjust font size here
      grow'=0,
      child anchor=west,
      parent anchor=south,
      align=left, base=bottom,
      anchor=west,
      calign=first,
      inner sep=0,
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      before typesetting nodes={
        if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom,  align=left, base=bottom]}}
        {}
      },
      fit=band,
      before computing xy={l=15pt},
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} abc
  [Parent
    [Child 1]
    [Child 2]
  ] 
\end{forest}
\end{document}


Will this work even if the content of nodes includes paragraph breaks? E.g. if you used align=p{} for example? I ask because I updated prooftrees to use \NewDocumentEnvironment, but specified +b just to be safe. (There isn't really much of a case for it in tableaux, but people do unexpected things with the package.)

As you say, paragraph breaks require +b. I have updated the post.
